# The first frame of the video does not appear when the software is opened in qml

Tags: qml, qmediaplayer

when the software is opened in qml, the first frame of the video does not appear. I am using videooutput and mediaplayer. When I researched, they suggested that I set the autoplay and autoload variables to true. but in the latest version I am using autoload and autoplay are not available in mediaplayer. How can I make the first frame appear on the screen even though I did not start the video when the software was first opened?

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtMultimedia
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

Item {
    id: videoContainer
    anchors.fill: parent
    Material.accent: sliderColor

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: mainBackgroundColor
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaPlayer
        videoOutput: videoOutput
        source: "vid1.mp4"
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        VideoOutput {
            id: videoOutput
            fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
            Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
        RowLayout {
            Layout.leftMargin: 5; Layout.rightMargin: 5
            Button {
                id: playPauseButton
                Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.fillWidth: true
                Material.background: '#148ca3'
                text: mediaPlayer.playbackState === MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? "Durdur" : "Başlat"
                onClicked: {
                    if (mediaPlayer.playbackState === MediaPlayer.PlayingState) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause()
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.play()
                    }
                }
            }
            Slider {
                id: progressBar
                Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.fillWidth: true
                from: 0
                to: mediaPlayer.duration
                value: mediaPlayer.position
                onValueChanged: mediaPlayer.position = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I updated the post. I added the relevant code @JarMan

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I ended up calling:

```
play();
QThread::msleep(500);
pause();
```

(my code is C++ not QML)